# Validação de campo via jQuery corretamente

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Tenho a seguinte validação para o `TextBox` de justificativa. Porém mesmo retornando a mensagem e clicando no botão OK o sistema valida a exclusão.

O certo, deveria retornar a mensagem e dar um focus no campo de justificativa, assim, impedindo que o sistema aceite sem justificativa e/ou com menos de 15 caracteres.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
$("[id$=btnExcluirPedido]").click(function () {
    var txtJust = $("[id$=txtJustificativaExc]");
    if (txtJust.val().length <= 15 || txtJust.val() == "") {
        $("[id$=txtJustificativaExc]").focus();
        alert("A justificativa deve conter no mínimo 15 caracteres.");
    }

    else {
        cancelPostback = false;
        GrabPageRequestManager();
    }

});
```

Comment: O que é feito depois dessa verificação no fluxo normal? Uma chamada Ajax? Um POST comum?

Comment: @LINQ apenas um post, nesse caso valida a exclusão no code behind. Mas só deveria entrar nessa parte, caso respeitasse os 15 caracteres minimos.

Comment: Você vai ter que cancelar o submit do form. Não tem nenhum lugar tentando interromper o fluxo normal das coisas, a única coisa que o código pede pra fazer é mostrar um alert.

Comment: @LINQ tudo bem, vou tentar desta forma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente usar o método `event.preventDefault()` para evitar que a ação de *post* seja realizada, assim:

```
$("[id$=btnExcluirPedido]").click(function (event) {
    var txtJust = $("[id$=txtJustificativaExc]");
    if (txtJust.val().length <= 15 || txtJust.val() == "") {
        $("[id$=txtJustificativaExc]").focus();
        alert("A justificativa deve conter no mínimo 15 caracteres.");
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    else {
        cancelPostback = false;
        GrabPageRequestManager();
    }

});
```